# Is $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} E(f(X_s)) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N f(k)$?

Tags: pr.probability, riemann-zeta-function, prime-number-theorem, expectation, probabilistic-number-theory

Let $s>1$ be a real number. We look at the zeta probability function / Zipf probability function defined as:

$$P(X = n) = \frac{1}{n^s \zeta(s)}$$

Suppose $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that the following limit exists:

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} E(f(X_s)) = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N f(k) P(X_s =k ) =$$

$$ = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N f(k) \frac{1}{k^s \zeta(s)} = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{f(k)}{k^s} = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{D_f(s)}{\zeta(s)}$$

where $D_f(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{f(k)}{k^s}$ is a Dirichlet series which converges for $s>1$ and the limit $= \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{D_f(s)}{\zeta(s)}$ is defined and exists.

**Question:** Is $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} E(f(X_s)) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N f(k)$?

If this can be proven, then the Prime number theorem would follow by plugging in $f(X_s) = \lambda(X_s)$ where $\lambda(n) = (-1)^{\Omega(n)}$ is the Liouville function, since it is known since Landau's doctoral thesis in 1899 that the right hand side

$$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N \lambda(k) = 0$$

is equivalent to the Prime number theorem.

But if the above question can be positively answered, then, since by Wikipedia we know that the left hand side is equal to:

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 1 }\frac{D_{\lambda}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{\zeta(2s)}{\zeta(s)^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)}{\infty} = 0$$

so the right hand side would also be equal to $0$ and the prime number theorem would follow.

Intuitively for $s \rightarrow 1$ the probability

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} P(X_s \equiv 0 \mod(n)) = \lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{1}{n}$$

equals the "probability that a random uniform natural number $X$ is divisible by $n$", which is $1/n$. So that is why I would expect the question to be positively answered, since it is a question about two expected values:

$$\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} E(f(X_s)) =^? \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^N f(k) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} E(f(X_N))$$

where $X_N$ is a random number $1 \le X_N \le N$ drawn uniformly with probability $1/N$.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is essentially asking about a version of the Tauberian theorem (as to whether the existence of the Dirichlet mean implies the existence of the Cesaro mean, and whether they coincide), such as in the case of Delange's Tauberian theorem. Although I don't have expertise in this topic, I believe that we need some extra conditions on $f$ just like in other Tauberian theorems.

Comment: @SangchulLee: I should have probably added, that in some circumstances / examples  I have computed, there are numerical examples where this is true, but I assume that one need some extra conditions on $f$. Thank you for mentionin the Delange's Tauberian theorem, which is helpful in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. E.g., if
$$f(k)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1})$$
for natural $k$, then
\begin{equation}
    Ef(X_s)\to\frac13 \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
as $s\downarrow0$, whereas
$$\frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$$
will be forever oscillating between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$ as $n\to\infty$.

Indeed, let $s\downarrow0$. Then $\zeta(s)\sim\frac1{s-1}$ and
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \zeta(s)Ef(X_s)&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f(k)}{k^s} \\  
    &=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^s}\sum_{j=0}^\infty 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^s} 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\Big(\int_{2^{2j}}^{2^{2j+1}}\frac{dk}{k^s}
    +O\Big(\frac1{2^{2sj}}\Big) \Big) \\  
    &=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{1-2^{1-s}}{s-1}\,2^{(1-s)2j}+O(1) \\  
    &\sim\frac1{3(s-1)}, 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so that \eqref{1} is proved.

On the other hand, letting
\begin{equation}
    s(n):=\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) 
\end{equation}
and letting a natural $m$ go to $\infty$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    s(2^{2m+2})&=s(2^{2m+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{2m+1}}\sum_{j=0}^\infty 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{2m+1}}\sum_{j=0}^m 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{j=0}^m\sum_{k=1}^{2^{2m+1}} 1(2^{2j}<k\le2^{2j+1}) \\  
    &=\sum_{j=0}^m 2^{2j}\sim\frac43\,2^{2m},   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so that
\begin{equation}
    \frac{s(2^{2m+2})}{2^{2m+2}}\to\frac13,
\end{equation}
whereas
\begin{equation}
    \frac{s(2^{2m+1})}{2^{2m+1}}\to\frac23.
\end{equation}
So,
\begin{equation}
    \frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)=\frac{s_n}n
\end{equation}
oscillates (at least) between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$ as $n\to\infty$, as was  claimed.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Comment: @mathoverflowUser : You are welcome. I guess you would have preferred a positive answer. Other than that, are you fully satisfied with this answer?